# How do I skip lines in the script?

Tags: python, skip, python-3.8

How do I skip over lines in my script (Python)

So I got Programm which asks you for several Inputs.
At the end it gives you a confirmation Question, but I included a function to load a profile in the first Input. It's supposed to skip you instantly to the Confirmation-Message without asking for the Other Inputs.

For **example**:

```
1 Name = input("What is your name? Type \"load\" to load your Profile")
2 if Name == "load":
3     #Code to skip to line 6
4 Salary = input("What is your salary?")
5 Age = input("How old are you?")
6 Confirmation = input("Are you sure about your Inputs?")
```

Now what Code should I include in line 3?
To compare: I search for a function like "*goto*" in bat-files.

(An obvious WorkAround is to add an If-Statement before every Input (expect the first & last one), and the If-Statement only gets changed if the first input is "load", but it's a little bit weird to look on, slowers Performance (even if it's not noticable) and is on the first look more complicated then it actually is.)

Comment: Yeah, you just wrap the other `input` calls in one `if` statement. There are no goto's in Python and there never will be.

Comment: Also variables and functions are named `lowercase_with_underscores` and `CapitalCase` is for class definitions.

Comment: Change it to `if name != "load"` and then indent lines 4 and 5 with 4 spaces and you got what you want. You'll need to define the default values of those variables before the if statement otherwise you'll get a NameError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using if statements are just fine. I don't think that you should worry about the performance of including them since their costs are negligible. If you are considered about having multiple if statements before checking your confirmation, you could check if anyone one of the user inputs require ones and if so ask for inputs, otherwise go straight to the confirmation.

```
1 Name = input("What is your name? Type \"load\" to load your Profile")
2 if Name != "load":
3     Salary = input("What is your salary?")
4     Age = input("How old are you?")
5 Confirmation = input("Are you sure about your Inputs?")
```